# Restrict acces to the folder but allow internal iframe PHP

Tags: php

I have a website, let's say: http://my-domain.com/site/gule/

On http://my-domain.com I'm using cms where I `Iframe src="/site/gule/index.php"`

I don't want people to be able access http://my-domain.com/site/gule/index.php but I still want to be able to iframe it within my framework.
Is that possible?

Comment: Probably not. iframe is just like opening a new tab in your browser, it acts the same. if you can access somewhere with an iframe, you can access it from the browser itself. you could generate some unique keys that you provide to your users and then verify those keys with your application, that's what I would do.

Comment: do you have some example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a key with md5 or whatever suits you best, once you have that key, just pass it on the url like so:
 http://my-domain.com/site/gule/index.php?secret=yourkey

on index.php file, extract the key from the $_GET global and compare it with the key you just made, if they are not the same stop the script.

fairly easy.

Comment: I had similar solution where I was comparing referrer unfortunately I'm getting server error when I use exit(); to stop the script. Any idea how to stop the script in a different way?

Comment: I got it, I was putting in wrong place. Thanks for the suggestion, I will prolly use the referrer when I found the right place where to call it.